# Is there a Cauchy integral formula for complex manifolds?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

Is there a Cauchy integral formula for holomorphic functions on complex manifolds?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [MO261860](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261860)? A short answer is that, if you can locally represent the location of the pole hypersurface as $z_1=0, z_2=0, \ldots$, you simultaneously use the residue for each of the complex coordinates $z_1,z_2,\ldots$, with Cauchy being a special case.